# Delphi 7, SelectDirectory with UNC

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I use Delphi 7 on Windows 7, I need to open a dialog that allow to choose a directory.
I use SelectDirectory (from unit FileCtrl).
The problem is that I want to navigate through an "unmapped" network directory, like `"\\10.0.0.1\Mickey"`.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck with the old fashioned `SelectDirectory` which is an obsolete and deprecated function.

On Vista and up you should use `IFileDialog` in its folder selection mode. For pre-Vista operating systems probably the best you can do is `SHBrowseForFolder`.

There is an overload of `SelectDirectory` that calls `SHBrowseForFolder`. It's the overload with 5 parameters. I don't know when it was introduced. Perhaps it's present even in Delphi 7. I also can't be sure whether or not `SHBrowseForFolder` will offer the directories that you are looking for.

Since you are also using an obsolete and deprecated version of Delphi then it's a bit more work to call `IFileDialog`. You'll need to declare the interface yourself and create and instance of it with `CoCreateInstance`.

Comment: `SHBrowseForFolder()`, and consequently the overloaded `SelectDirectory()`, does support network paths, just make sure the `Root` parameter is blank so that Network shares can appear in the dialog.

Comment: @RemyLebeau worthy of an answer I'd say!

Answer (score 2):

The Win32 `SHBrowseForFolder()` function, and consequently the RTL's overloaded `SelectDirectory()` function, does support network paths. Just set the `Root` parameter to a blank string so that network shares can appear in the dialog.

Comment: Was there an overloaded version in Delphi 7, though? I don't have anything earlier than 2007 installed here, but I don't remember there being one in D7.

Comment: Yes, the overload is available all the way back to D5, at least (I don't have the VCL sources for versions older than that).

Comment: Remy, thanks. As I said, I don't recall it being there (which, of course, just comments on my memory span <g>).

Comment: @KenWhite: that is why I like to keep the RTL/VCL source code for old versions, never know when they come in handy :-)

Comment: I may have to pull out some of the old CDs/DVDs. I still have D7 installed on one machine (but not this one), but dropped installing the others a while back when D2007 became stable.

Comment: Whenever I uninstall an IDE, I keep a copy of its `source` and `include` folders on my main development machine, just for reference purposes.

Comment: That's a good idea, except I typically never uninstall the IDE. It's usually that I get a new machine, and install the IDE versions I want onto that new system, so I don't carry them all forward. I may start at least transferring the source folders, though; it's a useful idea. Thanks. :-)

Comment: What I could not be sure was whether or not a location like \\10.0.0.1\Mickey would appear. Can you confirm that it will?

Comment: Yes, `SelectDirectory()` outputs a UNC path for a network share.